# RxJava : How to handle error with zip operator ?

Tags: android, error-handling, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am using RxJava and RxAndroid with Retrofit2.

```
Observable<ResponseOne> responseOneObservable = getRetrofitClient().getDataOne()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable<ResponseTwo> responseTwoObservable = getRetrofitClient().getDataTwo()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Using zip operator as below on above two Observer.

```
 Observable<ArrayList<TestData>> testDataObservable = Observable.zip(responseOneObservable, responseTwoObservable, new Func2<ResponseOne, ResponseTwo, ArrayList<TestData>>() {
            @Override
                public ArrayList<TestData> call(ResponseOne responseOne, ResponseTwo responseTwo) {
                  ArrayList<TestData> testDataList = new ArrayList();
                      // Add test data from response responseOne & responseTwo
                  return testDataList;
            } 
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<TestData>>() {

        @Override
        public void onNext(ArrayList<TestData> testDataList) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted" );
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError Throwable: " + t.toString() );
        }
    });
```

If there is any error occurs during retrofit http call in  `responseOneObservable` and `responseTwoObservable` then it will directly call `onError` method of subscriber of `testDataObservable`.

I want to continue in zip operator's `call` method even if anyone of two observable got success response.

How to handle error response using `zip` operator ?

Comment: I believe `onErrorResumeNext` should allow you to do this.

Comment: Do you know what to do if one of observables return NULL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334430/rxjava-group-two-responses-one-of-which-might-be-null-with-zip-operator

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `onErrorResumeNext` to return some Observable or `onErrorReturn` to return some default value to `zip`, like:

```
Observable.zip(
   responseOneObservable
       .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, ResponseOne>() {
        @Override
        public ResponseOne call(final Throwable throwable) {
            return new ResponseOne();
        }
    }),
   responseTwoObservable
       .onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, ResponseTwo>() {
        @Override
        public ResponseTwo call(final Throwable throwable) {
            return new ResponseTwo();
        }
    }),
   ...
```

See [onError handling](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators) for more info.

---

**UPDATE:** With RxJava 2.0 you must use `Function` instead of `Func1`:

```
import io.reactivex.functions.Function;
...
Observable.zip(
   responseOneObservable
       .onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, ResponseOne>() {
        @Override
        public ResponseOne apply(@NonNull final Throwable throwable) {
            return new ResponseOne();
        }
    }),
   responseTwoObservable
       .onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, ResponseTwo>() {
        @Override
        public ResponseTwo apply(@NonNull final Throwable throwable) {
            return new ResponseTwo();
        }
    }),
   ...
```

Or using lambdas:

```
Observable.zip(
   responseOneObservable
       .onErrorReturn(throwable -> new ResponseOne()),
   responseTwoObservable
       .onErrorReturn(throwable -> new ResponseTwo()),
   ...
```

Or using Kotlin:

```
Observable.zip(
   responseOneObservable
       .onErrorReturn { ResponseOne() },
   responseTwoObservable
       .onErrorReturn { ResponseTwo() },
   ...
```

Comment: Func1 has been replaced with Function in RxJava 2.0. REF: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0

Answer (score 4):

You can return default response from either of two observables with `onErrorResumeNext` operator.

```
Observable<ResponseOne> responseOneObservable = getRetrofitClient().getDataOne()
    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {/*some default value*/})
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable<ResponseTwo> responseTwoObservable = getRetrofitClient().getDataTwo()
    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {/*some default value*/})
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Also see [Error handling in RxJava - Dan Lew](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onErrorResumeNext` over the single zipped observables to instruct them emitting a default item in case of error.

Refer to [Error-Handling-Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators)